# get data and index when filtering data in array of object javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get data and index in same time using filter in javascript.

i have this array of object :

```
[
{
number: 123,
name: test1
},
{
number: 1234,
name: test14

},
{
number: 1235,
name: test15

},
{
number: 1236,
name: test16

},
]
```

by using filter:

```
let object = array.filter((value) => {

  return value.number == 1235;

}
```

Returning output of object successfully.

My goal is how to return index of this output in same code?

that mean return object value and index.

Without need to filter array again to get the index of value.

Comment: `array.indexOf(object)`?

Comment: No, that need to filter the array again to find the index. @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return anything inside filter though you can modify the object inside filter to add the index but that is not a good practice. Filter should be used to return the filtered object based on the given condition.You can use map with filter

```js
let arr=[
{
number: 1235,
name: 'test1'
},
{
number: 1234,
name: 'test14'

},
{
number: 1235,
name: 'test15'

},
{
number: 1236,
name: 'test16'

},
]

let object = arr.map((obj,index)=>{
return {...obj,index}
}).filter((value) => value.number == 1235)

console.log(object)
```

Or if you want to loop once only then use foreach

```js
    let arr=[
    {
    number: 1235,
    name: 'test1'
    },
    {
    number: 1234,
    name: 'test14'

    },
    {
    number: 1235,
    name: 'test15'

    },
    {
    number: 1236,
    name: 'test16'

    },
    ]

    let objct = [];
    arr.forEach((obj,index)=>{
      if(obj.number ==1235){
          objct.push({...obj,index})
      }
    })

    console.log(objct)
```

Comment: that exactly what i want, thank you! @jitender

Answer (score 1):

You can get index first:

```js
const idx = array.findIndex((value) => {
  return value.number == 1235;
});
```

and then get an object:

```js
const obj = array[idx];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a single item that corresponds to the filter criteria, in this case you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead:

```js
let index = array.findIndex(value => value.number == 1235);
```

You can also just find a single item using `find`:

```js
let item = array.find(value => value.number == 1235);
```

Then get the index with `indexOf`:

```js
let index = array.indexOf(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way it will work.

```js
let arr=[
{
number: 123,
name: 'test1'
},
{
number: 1234,
name: 'test14'

},
{
number: 1235,
name: 'test15'

},
{
number: 1236,
name: 'test16'

},
]

let fun = (value,index) => {
  value.index =index
  return value.number == 1235;

}
console.log([...arr].filter((value,index)=>fun(value,index))
)
```

Comment: modifying the object inside the filter function is not a good practice you should use filter for only filtering the array not modifying the array  state.Here original array will also be modified when you say ```value.index=index```

Comment: Yeah I completely agree with you. Therefore We can clone the array, I updated the code with that.

Comment: if you want to loop only once then use ```forEach``` with if condition

Comment: @jitender exactly!